# How to expand a text after clicking switch widget in android kotlin

Tags: kotlin, textview, switch-statement

I want my switch to open or expand a text field when checked on, or to minimize the text field when checked off. I can't help my self and find it on the internet.

I managed to make a button that opens a text but it can't minimize the text and also the button opens all the textboxes on that activity. Id also rather want to use a switch for my project.

Images as example below

[not expanded example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su0qw.jpg)

[expanded example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2SwT.jpg)

please help me 8( this is such an important thing for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a text or another text, you can do this:

```
@Composable
fun Switching() {
    var a = rememberSaveable{ mutableStateOf(false) }
    Switch(checked = a.value, onCheckedChange = { a.value = !a.value }, enabled = true)
    if(a.value) Text(text = "Hi, I'm here. how are you?")
    else Text(text = "I'm hidden")
}
```

Comment: Thank you kora, but i can't make it work. Im pretty new to coding and have a hard time implementing this. Can you make it more simple for me?